# Does asyncio allow co-existence of multiple implementations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Let's say in one application I would like to run quamash, aiozmq and aiohttp in different threads.

It should be possible to write custom event loop policy that would return appropriate loop e.g. based on name of a thread. However it's not clear what types of communications are supported between event loops from different providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can run `aiozmq` and `aiohttp` on `quamash` loop in the main thread. It just works.
2. If you really need to run different loops in different threads (I don't understand why, but you may have the desire) you should instantiate those loops manually. I doubt that event loop policy will be useful. It's convenient sometimes, but you have another case.

Comment: The reason is simple: many parallel services that need to exchange some data time to time. Neither ZMQ nor HTTP requests are results of actions in Qt GUI.

Comment: Will concurrency primitives like asyncio Event or Condition work between different loops?

Comment: Actually, I don't quite follow why aiozmq can work on quamash loop, while quamash cannot work on top of aiozmq loop. Could you explain?

Comment: No one asycnio concurrency primitive will work with multiple event loop -- that behavior is directly prohibited. The single method allowed to be called from different thread is `loop.call_soon_threadsafe()`.

Starting from aiozmq 0.5 `ZmqEventLoop` is not required, use [`create_zmq_connection()`](http://aiozmq.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/core.html#aiozmq.create_zmq_connection) coroutine for creating transport on top of every asyncio-compatible loop. Or switch to convenient [Streams API](http://aiozmq.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/stream.html)